# Cannot autowire service

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to implement UserManager from FOSUserBundle (Symfony3.4).

Service/Register.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager;


class Register
{
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManager $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public function register() {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsernameOrEmail('aaa@gmail.clom');
        if($user){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I try call this method I get:

> Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Service\Register": argument "$userManager" of method "__construct()" references class "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "fos_user.user_manager.default" service.

What should I do now?

Comment: Probably need to add an alias for the class.

Comment: Show us your services definition file.

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar problem (in Symfony 4, but the principles should apply to 3.4) with a different service and managed to find the answer on the Symfony doc page [Defining Services Dependencies Automatically (Autowiring)](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring).

Here's an extract from that page:

> The main way to configure autowiring is to create a service whose id exactly matches its class. In the previous example, the service's id is `AppBundle\Util\Rot13Transformer`, which allows us to autowire this type automatically.
>
> This can also be accomplished using an alias.

You need an alias because the service ID doesn't match the classname.  So do this:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # ...

    # the `fos_user.user_manager.default` service will be injected when
    # a `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager` type-hint is detected
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager: '@fos_user.user_manager.default'
```