# How to call a service in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, service, symfony-4.2

I want to generate XML feeds in Symfony 4 and I think that the [FeedBundle](https://github.com/eko/FeedBundle) is more than enough for me. I installed and configured it without any problem, my problem comes when I want to call the service from the Controller, his documentation tells to do the following:

```
$feed = $this->get('eko_feed.feed.manager')->get('article');
```

But in Symfony 4 that's not the right way to do as far as I know. Could someone let me know the right way to do it? I only need to know how to call the service from the controller, nothing more.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try inject service in controller.

Try adding in services.yaml:

```
services:

        Eko\FeedBundle\Feed\FeedManager: '@eko_feed.feed.manager'
```

In controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


    public function index(Request $request, \Eko\FeedBundle\Feed\FeedManager $feedmanager)
    {
        $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:YourEntity')->findAll();

        $feed = $feedmanager->get('article');
        $feed->addFromArray($articles);

        return new Response($feed->render('rss'));
    }
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952060/2776343)