# Symfony 6 service autowiring

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

So I have a very simple service for now. This is my services.yaml:

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

imports:
    - resource: myservice.yaml

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

and the file myservice.yaml is:

```
services:
 service.http_client:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Client
    public: true
    arguments:
      -
        timeout: 2.0
        base_uri: "%env(BASE_URI)%"
        handler: GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack
        headers:
          X-Api-Key: "%env(API_KEY)%"

  service.service_client:
    class: Service\V1alpha\ServiceClient
    arguments:
      - '%env(BASE_URI)%'
      - '@deeplink.http_client'
      - ~
      - ~
      - ''

  service:
    class: App\Service\Service
    public: true
    arguments:
      - "@service.service_client"
```

when I try to use it in my Controller like:

```
    public function __construct(private readonly Service $deeplinkService)
    {}
```

It constantly fails saying that `Service\V1alpha\ServiceClient` no such service exists. So this service clearly exists in ma `vendor` folder and the namespace is correct. What is the issue with autowiring here?

Comment: `Service` and `ServiceClient`  are different classes - why do you want to autowire one to the other? And how is ths a problem related to Composer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot autowire service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307819/cannot-autowire-service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see few things that are not necessary:

- Stop to declare aliases for your classes, use it directly.
- Declare only arguments you need (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#choose-a-specific-service)
- Avoid to declare classes into "public"

```yaml
services:
  Service\V1alpha\ServiceClient:
    arguments:
      $uri: '%env(BASE_URI)%'
      $ĥttpClient: '@deeplink.http_client'
```

And your class doesn't seems to be declared in your services.yaml (it is already done in `App\:` and `_defaults`), the container will be there for you.

```php
public function __construct(private readonly ServiceClient $deeplinkService)
{}
```